# How to watch 360 videos on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, vlc-media-player, youtube

My friend has been giving me MP4 files created using his Samsung Gear 360. Is there a way for me to watch them on Linux (for me, Ubuntu) without having to upload them to youtube/facebook?

I tried VLC but that didn't work.

I just want to use the arrow keys to look around the videos, just like facebook/youtube, but on my local system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- VLC 3.0.0 **stable** has been released and with the Linux version I'm able to play 360 content!
- I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.
- Install instructions:

  - https://itsfoss.com/install-latest-vlc/
  - http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/02/09/vlc-3-0-released-install-ubuntu/

I had trouble installing via the vlc PPA so I used Snap to install. Here's how I did it:

```
sudo apt purge 'vlc*' 'libvlc*'
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install vlc     # <== note: this is not 'apt'
```

Thanks to @Tomislav Nakic-Alfirevic for notifying us about the recent 3.0 release (Feb 2018).

Answer (score 1):

[VLC 3 declares support](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/3.0.0.html) for 360 video playback with "navigation".

Comment: Thanks! It works! Looks like VLC 3.0 was released around Feb 9, 2018. I used "sudo snap install vlc" to install it (NOTE: the 'snap'). I had to uninstall my 2.X version.

Comment: As noted in another comment, 'Spatial Media Metadata Injector' is needed in order for (some) 360 videos to work with VLC - the video files must contain the required metadata.

Answer (score 1):

'Spatial Media Metadata Injector' needs to used with the file to inject metadata, then it will work as a flat picture in VLC 3

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [VR Player for Linux](https://sht-vr-player.cf) because I was in a similar situation as you. The search for suitable software did not materialize. Well, enough to endure it - I decided, and started developing this application. So sht-vr-player appeared, and I hope that it will be useful to you as well as to me.

What can it do?

- View directory, convenient preview of media files.
- Support vr-photo (jpg)
- Support vr-video (mp4 - up to 4K, limitations in chrome, I hope they
  fix it soon)
- Ability to delete unnecessary media
- Ability to clear accumulated cache

It is available under MIT licence.

Comment: it's simple, because that's exactly what Charles Sampson asked.

What it can?

View directory, convenient preview of media files.
Support vr-photo (jpg)
Support vr-video (mp4 - up to 4K, limitations in chrome, I hope they fix it soon)
Ability to delete unnecessary media
Ability to clear accumulated cache

Comment: MIT licence, feel free to use

Comment: Thank you, looks much better now!

Comment: https://sht-vr-player.cf/ doesn't work any more. Where are the sources? Are they at https://gitlab.com/go-apps-XnjRcS/vr-viewer-for-linux ?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/go-apps-XnjRcS/vr-viewer-for-linux/electron-version

Answer (score 0):

You may install the GoPro VR Player that is available for Linux. 
It does work for HD on my machine, but is too slow for 4k. Depends on the machine I guess.
I did not get VLC 3 to work up to now unfortunately.